# Any way to use nodemon + debugger with Cloud9 IDE?

Tags: cloud9-ide, nodemon

The javascript debugger in Cloud9 is great, but it only appears to work if I run 'node' rather than using something like 'nodemon'.

I'd like the run command to restart if a file changes, and I also want to use the debugger. Anyone know a quick fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Discovered that there's no need to restart the runner - changes are applied to the run environment / configuration immediately. Even better!

Answer (score 0):

That's what I wanted to write, it applies changes automatically.
Though, if you make changes to routes, you have to restart the server,
at least that's what I was having to do.